# Tidyverse min{x, 1-x} by column

Tags: r, tidyverse

My data is the following:

```
tibble(var1.q = 0.01, var2.q = .99, var3.q = .45) -> foo
```

I would like to calculate 2 * min{x, 1-x} for each column.

In base R, I could do

```
 2*apply(bind_rows(foo, 1-foo), 2, FUN=min)
```

but I struggle to find the tidyverse equivalent of this.

Expected result:

```
  0.02   0.02   0.90
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution, using `pmin` (parallel min) to calculate the `min` rowwise:

```r
library(dplyr)

foo %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ 2 * pmin(.x, 1-.x) ))

#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   var1.q var2.q var3.q
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1   0.02 0.0200    0.9
```

Comment: Thank you PaulS! Just to understand: since I do not have a group_by() call are summarise() and mutate() equivalent?

Comment: Actually, @OttoKässi, it is not very clear your post. And I am not sure whether you want to summarise or not. The best would be to edit your post, adding some more rows to your dataframe and the expected result.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `across(everything)` to create summaries of each column and then define an anonymous function `function(x) 2 * min(x, 1-x)` to perform the summary calculation.

```
library(dplyr)
foo %>% summarise(across(everything(), function(x) 2 * min(x, 1-x)))
```

```
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  var1.q var2.q var3.q
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1   0.02 0.0200    0.9
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `pmin` directly over `foo` and `1-foo`

```
> 2 * pmin(foo, 1 - foo)
  var1.q var2.q var3.q
1   0.02   0.02    0.9
```